# i have converted select options into buttons.It works fine in pc but not working in mobiles

Tags: html, css

I have styled select options and convert into buttons.It works fine in desktop/laptop but not working in mobiles.How can i fix that?? Anyone help please..
here is the full code of select options and css with images.
please check that and tell me why this is not working in mobile

[image]

[image]

```css
.property_for {
  border: none !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  scrollbar-width: none !important;
  background: none !important;
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
  width: 300px;
  height: 175px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  white-space: normal;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.property_for::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0 !important;
}

.property_for:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}

.property_for option {
  width: 46% !important;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 10px !important;
  padding: 20px 0 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  margin: 3px !important;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000000;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

select option:active {
  background-color: #e91e63 !important; /* for IE */
  color: #fff !important;
}

select.property_for option:checked {
  background: linear-gradient(#e91e63, #e91e63) !important;
  background-color: #e91e63 !important; /* for IE */
  color: #fff !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<select
  class="property_for"
  id="property_for1"
  title="Looking For"
  onchange="get_select_option(this.value)"
  multiple
  style="text-align: center; width: 100%; height: 120px"
>
  <option value="Buy" selected style="width: 45% !important">Buy</option>
  <option value="Rent" style="width: 45% !important">Rent</option>
  <option value="wanted for sale" style="width: 45% !important">
    Wanted For Sale
  </option>
  <option
    value="wanted for rent"
    style="margin-top: 10px; width: 45% !important"
  >
    Wanted For Rent
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: 'It works fine in desktop/laptop but not working in mobiles.' What exactly? Can you be more specific? On a side note, I see you're using the `!important` property **a lot**. Make sure to use it only when necessary, as it won't make it easier to make your page responsive.

Comment: dear i put images in question.check that images you will understand the problem

Comment: and i think important property doesnt matter in this case.because i used different classes for responsive and pc view

Comment: Please make your code into a runnable snippet - it makes it much easier for us to see the problem for ouselves, especially on mobiles.  What mobilebrowser/OS are you testing on?

Comment: tried -webkit-appearance::none  ? looks like the browser forces a selectbox

Comment: tried it on emulator, doesnt work.. i suggest you use radiobuttons or checkboxes instead to bypass the mobile device default UI.

Comment: -webkit-appearance:none not working bro

Comment: anyone have solution?? please help..